# Button that returns user to the previous auth type

Tags: java, keycloak

In project I'm working on there are two auth types. First one is "Sms Or Phone Auth Action", second - "User Selection Post Form".
Once user passes the first one, "Sms Or Phone Auth Action", he is in "User Selection Post Form". I need to implement to following:

when user passes 1st auth, he should have an ability to turn back the 1st auth from 2nd one.

[image: auth types]

I tried putting loginAction to the button that should turn user to the prev auth type - it failed.
Tried to just return page of 1st auth type - it failed.

Using methods of AuthenticationFlowContext like cancel login and etc - failed.